# Flutter TextFormField onSave() get called with empty values

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield

I want to do a Custom TextFormField so I call it when I want, but `valuedata` property inside onSave() keeps being empty after passing the data to it.
Here is the custom TextFormField:

```
class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomTextField({
    Key? key,
    required this.labelText,
    required this.textInputType,
    required this.message,
    required this.valuedata,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String labelText;
  final TextInputType textInputType;
  final String message;
  String valuedata;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      onSaved: (value) {
        valuedata = value!;
      },
      keyboardType: textInputType,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelStyle: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          labelText: labelText,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          )),
      validator: (text) {
        if (text!.isEmpty) {
          return message;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here where I use it:

```
 CustomTextField(
                      valuedata: input.input1,
                      labelText: 'name',
                      message: 'Please enter your name',
                      textInputType: TextInputType.text,
                    ),
```

and this is the full code where I use the CustomTextField:

```
class Apply extends StatefulWidget {
  const Apply({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ApplyState createState() => _ApplyState();
}

class Data {
  String input1 = '';
  String input2 = '';
}

class _ApplyState extends State<Apply> {
  var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static Data input = Data();
  var input1 = '';
  var input2 = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Theme(
          data: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.green),
          child: Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      "Les informations Personneles:",
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    CustomTextField(
                      valuedata: input.input1,
                      //data: data,
                      labelText: 'Prenom',
                      message: 'Please enter your name',
                      textInputType: TextInputType.text,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 16,
                    ),
                    CustomTextField(
                      valuedata: input.input2,
                      labelText: 'Prenom',
                      message: 'Please enter your name',
                      textInputType: TextInputType.text,

                      //d,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: Colors.red,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  formKey.currentState!.reset();
                                  input1 = '';
                                  input2 = '';
                                  setState(() {});
                                },
                                child: const Text('Clear'))),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 16,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: Colors.green,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                    formKey.currentState!.save();

                                    setState(() {});
                                  }
                                },
                                child: const Text('show'))),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 16,
                    ),
                    Text('Input1: ${input.input1}'),
                    Text('Input2: ${input.input1}'),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 16,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you refer to the image input1 and input2 doesn't get the user Inputs.
My question is, with this same approach how can make the onSave() save the values on the state?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for

```
class Apply extends StatefulWidget {
const Apply({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ApplyState createState() => _ApplyState();
}

class Data {
  List<String> inputs = ['',''];
}

class _ApplyState extends State<Apply> {
  var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static Data input = Data();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Theme(
          data: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.green),
          child: Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      "Les informations Personneles:",
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    createTextField('label1', TextInputType.datetime, 'msg', 0),
                    createTextField('label2', TextInputType.datetime, 'msg', 1),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: Colors.red,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  formKey.currentState!.reset();
                                  //input1 = '';
                                  //input2 = '';
                                  setState(() {});
                                },
                                child: const Text('Clear'))),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 16,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: Colors.green,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                    formKey.currentState!.save();

                                    setState(() {});
                                  }
                                },
                                child: const Text('show'))),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 16,
                    ),
                    Text('Input1: ${input.inputs[0]}'),
                    Text('Input2: ${input.inputs[1]}'),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 16,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  createTextField(String labelText, TextInputType textInputType, String message, int index) => TextFormField(
      onSaved: (value) {
        setState(() {
          input.inputs[index] = value!;
        });
      },
      keyboardType: textInputType,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelStyle: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          labelText: labelText,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          )),
      validator: (text) {
        if (text!.isEmpty) {
          return message;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    );
}
```

Comment: I was doing the exact thing but I wanted to reduce the code because I'll have several TextFields, Thank you so much for your answer anyways Abdallah.

Comment: @YassineBENNKHAY you can create a function within the same class that returns a textfield, where you can access the state directly, but you will have to store the inputs in an array, and use index to specify the array index to change in the function, for ex call it createTextField(String labelText, TextInputType textInputType, String message, int index), and in your state you will have an array of inputs: List<String> inputs = ['', ''], and in the function's setState you will set the element at the specified index

Comment: can you please edit your answer with this function?

Comment: @YassineBENNKHAY Check it now

Comment: It worked fine, it was a good solution, I did not think of it that way! I'm going to give it an upvote and I would be happy to connect with you on LinkedIn, I added you there!